# std::string character encoding

Tags: c++, utf-8, stdstring

```
std::string arrWords[10];
std::vector<std::string> hElemanlar;
```

......

```
this->hElemanlar.push_back(std::string(1, this->arrWords[sayKelime][j]).c_str());
```

......

What i am doing is: Every element of arrWord is a std::string. I get the n th element of arrWord and then push them into hElemanlar.

Assuming arrWords[0] is "test", then:

```
this->hElemanlar.push_back("t");
this->hElemanlar.push_back("e");
this->hElemanlar.push_back("s");
this->hElemanlar.push_back("t");
```

And my problem is although i have no encoding problems with arrWords, some utf-8 characters are not printed or treated well in hElemanlar.
How can i fix it?s

Comment: We cannot help when your problem statement is just _"some utf-8 characters are not printed or treated well"_

Comment: I'm sure there is no problem for "test". Can you show some string that does have a problem?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well the problem is that some utf-8 characters are not printed or treated well.

Comment: Repeating the same statement does not add value either.

Comment: @BoPersson like "ğ,ş,ı,ö,ç,ü".

Comment: You need to use [`std::wstring`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/) (or a custom type) if you want to use wide character set.

Comment: @Holt thanks i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `arrWords[i]` contains UTF-8 encoded text, then you probably need to split the strings into complete Unicode characters.

As an aside, rather than saying:

```
this->hElemanlar.push_back(std::string(1, this->arrWords[sayKelime][j]).c_str());
```

(which constructs a temporary std::string, obtains a the c-string representation of it, constructs *another* temporary string, and pushes that onto the vector), say:

```
this->hElemanlar.push_back(std::string(1, this->arrWords[sayKelime][j]))
```

Anyway.  This will need to become something like:

```
std::string str(1, this-arrWords[sayKelime][j])
if (static_cast<unsigned char>(str[0]) >= 0xC0)
{
   for (const char c = this-arrWords[sayKelime][j+1];
        static_cast<unsigned char>(c) >= 0x80;
        j++)
   {
       str.push_back(c);
   }
}
this->hElemenlar.push_back(str);
```

Note that the above loop is safe, because if `j` is the index of the last char in the string, `[j+1]` will return the nul-terminator (which will end the loop).
You will need to consider how incrementing j interacts with the rest of your code though.

You then need to consider whether you want `hElemanlar` to represent individual Unicode code points (which this does), or do you want to include a character + all the combining characters that follow?  In the latter case, you would have to extend the code above to:

- Parse the next code-point
- Decide whether it is a combining character
- Push the UTF-8 sequence on the string if so.
- Repeat (you can have multiple combining characters on a character).

Comment: Unfortunately it is crashing.